# easy way to insert an selected dataset with doctrine

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

is there an easy way in doctrine to load a dataset (maybe with

```
$dataset = $em->getRepository($entity)->find($id);
```

) change some values and then insert (!) this modified dataset into the table with a simple call to flush()? So I want to have a new dataset with new generated autovalue and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dataset = $em->getRepository($entity)->find($id);
$dataset2= new $entity;
$dataset2->setZip($dataset->getZip());
$em->persist($account);
$em->flush();
```

This way you can set a new value for your items and flush them but if you have lots of fields and just you want to modify some minor fields its better you Use QueryBuilder and return an arrayResult and not an object(which is returned by find command):

```
 $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
 $qb->add('select', 'a')
->add('from', 'Entities\Account a')
->add('where', 'a.zip = :zip')
->add('orderBy', 'a.username ASC')
->setParameter('zip', '20171');
 $query = $qb->getQuery();
 $dataset = $query->getArrayResult();

 //Modify your array and then use the following class to serialize the array to a flushable array object
$entityUtil = new Cob\Doctrine\ORM\EntityUtil ( $this->em );
$dataset2 = $entityUtil->createEntity (new $entity,$dataset);
$em->persist($dataset2);
$em->flush();


 get entityutil from [here][1]
```

You see? Doing some simple tasks in doctrine is a big pain.